# Actions on Google - no input prompts being asked as part of conversation flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I've been looking at the best practice guides for actions on google and specifically I'm trying to implement a 'repeat' feature as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices#let_users_replay_information)

Now it doesn't help that the sample code references params/functions that aren't defined but specifically it looks like you should be able to pass a 'NO_INPUT_PROMPTS' argument to `conv.ask()` so in the event the user doesn't answer within a specified time it then uses these to prompt them. From my understanding this could be a string or array.

The trouble is, when I pass an array into the function, it actually stops my action from working. If I pass a string, then it concatenates it to the initial question rather than acting as a reprompt.

Can anyone help with how this should work. My code is as follows:

```
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});
const NO_INPUT_PROMPTS = ['Would you like to answer the question?'];

function ask(conv, inputPrompt, noInputPrompts) {
    conv.data.lastPrompt = inputPrompt;
    conv.data.lastNoInputPrompts = noInputPrompts;
    conv.ask(inputPrompt,noInputPrompt);
}

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
    let message = "Hello what's your favourite color";
    ask(conv,message,NO_INPUT_PROMPTS);
})
```

Looking at the code at https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/master/src/service/actionssdk/conversation/conversation.ts#L431 when I call `ask` it's actually appending it to the array of responses and they all get read out together, rather than being interpreted as a reprompt. Does someone know what the missing 'link' of code is here?

I'm using v2.2.0 of the `actions-on-google` on library and NodeJS v8. The intents are created in dialogflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical! So after trying to figure this out over 2 days, just after posting the question I stumbled upon what might be a solution.

I think the issue is you need to explicitly set the conv.noInputs property, rather than passing it in as part of ask. I'm going to submit this as a documentation bug so hopefully it won't catch others out.

```
function ask(conv, inputPrompt, noInputPrompts) {
    conv.data.lastPrompt = inputPrompt;
    conv.data.lastNoInputPrompts = noInputPrompts;
    conv.noInputs = noInputPrompts
    conv.ask(inputPrompt);
}
```